# Change html code from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

I guess this is very simple for some of you, but so far I tried a few things and none worked. I have a php file, which displays a form, where the user clicks. I want to change a bit of the code depending on what the user selects from a dropdown menu, but without hitting submit. For example, the user selects option 1 and `<div id="option1"><img src="something.jpg"/></div>` displays. The user selects option 2 and instead `<div id="option2"><img src="something2.jpg"/></div>` displays below. I was looking into onchange and a function, but was unclear how to display divs in that function. I guess the value of `<option value="...` can't be a div. So how should I approach this? All that happens in a php file. Thanks a lot in advance, any guidance and ideas will be helpful.

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="1">option 1
  <option value="2">option 2
  <option value="3">option 3
</select>
```

What is different here from the marked as duplicate question is that it is part  of a php file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code

Comment: you can add an [onchange()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event to the select, which checks the value.

Comment: Thank you, I was just editing what I wrote as I noticed the code didn't display.